# Package Route in IIS?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, api, iis, flask-restful

We have two environment on IIS, One is Testing Environment and other is Staging Environment. We have deployed all our python code in two similar structure folder, one is for testing_codes and the other is for Staging_codes. In our python codes we used to call a package for importing modules, for testing environment it is working fine but for staging it is not working because whenever I call any module from the package it is picking all my modules from testing environment.it was supposed to take all modules from staging environment???
I don't have any idea why it is pointing to testing_codes when I import modules from my package?

Comment: How did you isolate the test environment and staging environment?  Please post more details about your IIS configuration.

Comment: I have created two environment python staging and testing using wfastcgi, I have installed two flask application one is for staging and another one is for testing with same name but path is different. Basically staging environment is the replica of testing except path. App name and the handler name is same for both environment.